# Python Dataframe Concatenation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am looping through the days of the week and grabbing data from a database in 15 minute intervals. Every time I loop through a day, I am grabbing the appropriate data and placing in a Dataframe using pd.concat. I am using Pandas to do this.

Every time I go to the next day, however, it seems that the data doesn't get added to the intended position. For example, this is what the dataframe looks like:

```
    1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3
1   x   x   x
2   x   x   x
3   x   x   x
4               x   x   x
5               x   x   x
6               x   x   x
7                           x   x   x
8                           x   x   x
9                           x   x   x
```

Instead of what it should look like:

```
    1   2   3
1   x   x   x
2   x   x   x
3   x   x   x
4   x   x   x
5   x   x   x
6   x   x   x
7   x   x   x
8   x   x   x
9   x   x   x
```

Each 'block' of data represents a day, and I would like them stacked on top of each other rather than offset by the previous day.

When I print the dataframes to my console, it seems that the empty cells to the left of the data are NaN, but when I tried to remove those NaN values, nothing changed.

I would love any input, or if you need more information to provide a helpful answer let me know and I can try to add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you want to use:

```
pd.concat(..., ignore_index=True)
#              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: thanks for the input, i tried that but it unfortunately didn't work. what does ignore_index do that should fix the issue?

Comment: @VinodKrishnamurthy, can you post two small __reproducible__ data sets   (in CSV/text form) and your desired data set so we could reproduce your issue?

Comment: sure, but do you think you could clarify what exactly you are asking for?

Comment: @VinodKrishnamurthy, i'm asking for data sets which would help to reproduce the issue. Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)